# Winforms panel won't show after I add a forms page to controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, syncfusion

In the code below I will check which node is selected. Based on that I will show different forms in the panel (which you can see in the picture). Now everything works fine beside when I try to show the panel it stays blank. Nothing will show when I add the form to the controls of the panel.

```
Private Sub CheckForChildren(ByVal node As TreeNodeAdv)
    ' check whether each parent node has child nodes 
    If node.HasChildren AndAlso node.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
        ' iterate through child nodes in the collection
        For Each childNode As TreeNodeAdv In node.Nodes
            If childNode.IsSelected Then
                Console.WriteLine(childNode.Text & " is selected")
                If childNode.Name = "cnKlanten" Then
                    pnlHome.Controls.Clear()
                    Dim form As frmClients = New frmClients
                    form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                    form.TopLevel = False
                    pnlHome.Controls.Add(form)
                    pnlHome.BringToFront()
                    pnlHome.Show()
                End If
            End If
            ' Do recursive call
            CheckForChildren(childNode)
        Next childNode
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Layout application]

I tried hiding it first which doesn't seem to help.
I also have read a couple related post on here and other forums. And I also watched some videos on YouTube.
But all of them just show me how I did it but their panel will show and I can't see any difference.

Comment: don't put whole forms in a panel. They try to do things with events and window management that don't make sense as children of other controls. If you need to do this, build them as user controls

Comment: Why keep showing forms, just to recurse and possibly remove and replace it with another one? Do all of your recursion and figure out what the proper form should be, then display it. Or, if you should stop after you find the first one, then don't keep recursing...